# copy-mangar having auto-poweroff after completing copying/moving operations?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, transfer

Many Of my friends don't have Internet connection so often i download their stuffs.
so sometime the files are too large 20~25 GB's . Which takes hours to copy :)

For my convenient  is there any way to add feature of "**Power off Device after completing copying**".

Similar to application named  **Terra-Copy**  on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer command-line way, yes you can do it with the following command. But you need to make the `shutdown` command that does not require your password to run by editing the `visudo` file:

```
rsync -ap /source /destination && sudo shutdown -h now
```

The `-P` or `--partial` flag prevents incomplete files from begin deleted if there is an interruption. If you run the same command again, any incomplete transfer will be resumed.

For making `shutdown` command to run without entering your password, run `sudo visudo` and add the following line at the END in the file that opens:

```
Your_USERNAME  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Then exit the editor and save it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

Now your computer will shutdown after the copy finish.

---

Also you can use graphical rsync `grsync` tool. Install `grsync`:

```
sudo apt-get install grsync
```

After you installed, open the dash and type `grsync` end hit enter to open it.

Configure the hints(1-5) and press start button(6) to start the copy.

1. click on "Basic options" tab
2. type your *source path* in first text-box or click on "Open" button
3. type your *destination path* in next text-box.
4. click on "Extra options" tab
5. type your command in text-box below "Execute this command after rsync" that will be execute when copy gets finish.

   there is also an option for executing the command before starting `grsync` copy progress.
6. and finally click "Start copy" button (upper right corner in grsync window)

[image]

Note that to executing the shutdown command without your password you need to edit `visudo` file as mentioned in above.

Don't forget checking the resume support option from "Advanced options" tab:

[image]